# Getting 'Undefined' when searching through array of quotes - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I am working on a random quote generator, where I first randomly generate a number between 0 and the length of the array 'quotes,' then return that quote.

```
function getQuote() {
 var quotes = ["I never met a toby that I didn't like ~ Kimya Dawson", "Blood in my beard ~ Aesop Rock", "How many roads must a man walk down? ~ Bob Dylan", "Orange is the new black ~ Jenji Kohan"];

function randomNumber(min, max) {
 var quote = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min
 return quotes[quote]; 
}; 
return randomNumber(0, quotes.length);
};
getQuote();
```

It works most of the time, but every so often it will return 'Undefined.' I did not have this problem when testing with an array of single words like 'hello,' 'green,' etc., it only happens when I add spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min
```

can return `max` which points to a non-existing array element. Array indices go from `0` to `length - 1`.

It should be

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
```

Answer (score 1):

That `+1` in the code that finds a random index is your problem.

There are 4 quotes, so `max` is 4.  `4-0+1` is 5, not 4, so you're going to generate the value `4` every once in a while, and there is nothing at that position in the array. (The quotes are at indexes 0, 1, 2, and 3.)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays starts from 0, so in your case max is 3 (quotes[3]).
However length function returns number of elements (4).

```
return randomNumber(0, quotes.length-1);
```